# How to undelete an answer?

Tags: discussion

How do I vote to undelete an answer to this question:
[MicroSD Card High Speed Adapter?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5513/microsd-card-high-speed-adapter)

I've answered it and I've edited my answer as well, yet it is still deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer was deleted because it did not provide a recommendation to answer the question.

When you posted your answer, the first line in it read

> is the SD card UHS or not?

swiftly followed by

> So need more info from you.

That kind of stuff needs to go in comments, not in answers. If you want clarification, extra information, etc, use a comment.

As for the recommendation you did provide, you recommended an SD card. That didn't answer the question, because the question asked for a high-speed microSD adapter. That's not the same as an SD card. That left your answer offering:

- a comment, and
- a recommendation that didn't answer the question,

so I deleted it.

If you want it to be undeleted, you need to edit in a recommendation of hardware that fits the question, as I said in a comment.

Comment: Seems like the accepted answer is an SD card as well.

Comment: @AndriyLysak Yes. But it also provides the information that the requested device does not exist, which is what makes it an answer.